# how to align img inside the div to the right?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to align the image inside the div on the right side?

Comment: Related: [right align an image using CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214893/)

Answer (score 59):

You can give the surrounding `div` a

```
text-align: right
```

this will leave white space to the left of the image. (= the image will occupy the whole line).

If you want content to be shown to the left hand side of the image, use

```
float: right
```

on the image. However, the surrounding `div` will then need `overflow: auto` to stretch to the needed height.

Comment: You can apply `display: inline` or `inline-block` if you want to get rid of the white space yet retain the right alignment for text.

Comment: It's weird that the the property `text-align` applies to things that aren't text.

Answer (score 24):

```
<div style="width:300px; text-align:right;">
        <img src="someimgage.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p>
  <img style="float: right; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;" src="files/styles/large_hero_desktop_1x/public/headers/Kids%20on%20iPad%20 %202400x880.jpg?itok=PFa-MXyQ" width="100" />
  Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci. 
  <br style="clear: both;" />
</p>
```

Comment: You should comment your answer and format your code. Now it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to align with CSS, each one has it's benefits and disadvantages, you could test them all to check which one fits your case better:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

**TIP:** Always search using **W3** as extra word, that will give you in first places the resources of the W3school website or the w3.org if there's any relevant.

Answer (score -1):

`vertical-align:middle; text-align:right;`

Answer (score -3):

```
<style type="text/css">
>> .imgTop {
>>  display: block;
>>  text-align: right;
>>  }
>> </style>

<img class="imgTop" src="imgName.gif" alt="image description" height="100" width="100">
```

Comment: Wrong. `text-align: right` should be applied to the parent `<div>`.