# right align an image using CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I right-align an image using CSS.

I **do not** want the text to `wrap-around` the image. I want the right aligned image to be on a line by itself.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
<img style="float: right;" alt="" src="http://example.com/image.png" />
<div style="clear: right">
   ...text...
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aHyL/).

Answer (score 34):

```
 img {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
   }
```

Comment: @Ani Outlook likes this better than floats.

Comment: Floats become tricky in responsive design and require extra psudo or real elements in the dom. With this solution, the code is simple and maintainable.

Answer (score 14):

Float the image right, which will **at first** cause your text to wrap around it.

Then whatever the very **next** element is, set it to { clear: right; } and everything will stop wrapping around the image.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few different ways to do this but following is a quick sample of one way.

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" style="float:right" /><div style="clear:both">Your text here.</div>
```

I used inline styles for this sample but you can easily place these in a stylesheet and reference the class or id.

Answer (score 7):

To make the image move right:

```
float: right;
```

To make the text not wrapped:

```
clear: right;
```

For best practice, put the css code in your stylesheets file. Once you add more code, it will look messy and hard to edit.

Answer (score 7):

My workaround for this issue was to set `display: inline` to the image element.
With this, your image and text will be aligned to the right if you set `text-align: right` from a parent container.

Comment: Excellent solution for emails because Outlook doesn't seem to like floats.

Answer (score -1):

#### Easier / more organized way to do this is with some css.

> CSS Above, HTML below with the snippet.

```css
div {
  clear: right;
}


/*
img {
   float:right
}*/


/* img part is unneeded unless you want it to be a image on the right the whole time */
```

```html
<html>
<!-- i am using an image from my website as a quick example-->
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ksIsCute/GtGraffiti/gh-pages/icon.ico" alt="my image!" style=float:right>
<div>My Text Here</div>
<!-- Text goes below the image, and not beside it.-->
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ksIsCute/GtGraffiti/gh-pages/icon.ico" alt="my image!" style=float:right>
<div>
  <h1> I support headers! </h1>
  <blockquote> And blockquotes!! </blockquote>
  and <a href="">hyperlinks!</a>
</div>
<!-- THE CODE BELOW HERE IS **NOT** NEEDED!! (except for the </html>) -->
<h2 style="text-align:center;color:Grey;font-family:verdana"> Honestly I hope this helped you, if there is any error to my work please feel free to tell me. </h2>

</html>
```