# Put an image on the right side of the page

Tags: html, css, image

So I have this webpage in Html and CSS, and I have this contact page. But I have this image I want to put on the right side of the page, but if I do: `float: right;` it doesn't seem to work. I also tried align but apparently the only thing close to that is `text-align`. If needed, here is my code (HTML):
    
    
    
        
        CherryPlaysRoblox

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <p id="Cherry">CherryPlaysRoblox1</p>
</ul>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<h4>Here are a few ways you can contact me. I will update the page when I change anything.</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- EMAIL -->
<img src="_gmail.png" alt="gmail" height="30" width="35"> <h4>My email</h4>
<!-- TWITTER -->
<img src="_twitter.png.png" alt="twitter" height="35" width="35"> <h4>Username</h4>
<!-- FACEBOOK -->
<img src="_facebook.png" alt="facebook" height="35" width="35"> <h4>Username</h4>
<!-- INSTAGRAM -->
<img src="_instagram.png" alt="instagram" height="35" width="35"> <h4>Username</h4>
<!-- ME -->
<div id="PhotoOfMe">
    <img src="_Cherry.png" alt="Me" id="Me">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS code:

```
#Cherry {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
}    
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: DarkOrchid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}    
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid White;
}    
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
li a:hover {
    background-color: PaleVioletRed;
}    
.active {
    background-color: PaleVioletRed;
}    
/*JUMBOTRON*/
.jumbotron {
    background-color: Sandybrown !important;
    float: top; 
}    
.jumbotron, p + h1 {
    color: black !important;
    font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
}  
/*BODY*/
body {
    background-color: Peachpuff !important;
}    
h2 {
    font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive !important;
} 
h4 {    
}    
#me {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

I'd appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [right align an image using CSS HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214893/right-align-an-image-using-css-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct floating it needs to be at the top, then it will float right into whatever comes afterwards in the document, so if you push the `#me` container above the `#email` it's going to be aligned on the right side. Also in your HTML the id was uppercase `Me`and in the css it was lowercase `#me`.

So push it to the top and change it to lowercase:

```
...
<!-- ME -->
<div id="PhotoOfMe">
    <img src="_Cherry.png" alt="Me" id="me">
</div>
<!-- EMAIL -->
<img src="_gmail.png" alt="gmail" height="30" width="35"> <h4>My email</h4>
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It actually worked! Also one more questions: If you're floating something, does the item have to be before anything else on the body in the middle?

Comment: Your're welcome. it needs to be before the element where it floats "into". you can find examples on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float. I also suggest you look into css flexbox because it's way easier to create multi column layouts with it, see here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks so much! I'll totally check it out!