# How to justify image to the right

Tags: css

[image: Screenshow what I want to achieve]

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
        <div class="headerText">
            <span>WYJĄTKOWA PIOSENKA NA URODZINY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a problem. I would like to justify the `<span>` to right.

Comment: Did you try writing an CSS yet? See this [documentation on aligning DIV](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp). Check the documentation and do some experimenting. You can use jsfiddle.net to do quick experimenting.

Comment: Do you intend to align the text right in the headerText element, or the headerText element right in relation to header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [right align an image using CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214893/right-align-an-image-using-css-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem with `float:right` is that it creates a new line if the preceding sibling is a block element or the element itself has no space to fit in, like the text. But text can break to a newline if necessary.

And here comes the use of `display:flex;`.

With flex, you are creating columns of its children, which is similar to `float:left` by using `flex-direction:row` on the parent element. And in case you need an element to float right, just give it a `margin-left:auto;`

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.headerText {
  margin-left: auto;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://novaservis.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/small-cute-dog-breeds-that-stay-smallbest-25-types-of-small-dogs-ideas-on-pinterest-types-of-dogs-exciting.jpg" id="logo" />
  <div class="headerText">
    <span>WYJĄTKOWA PIOSENKA NA URODZINY</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is it over complicating? Could you be specific??

Comment: Flex classs and empty rules, GTG back in 10

Comment: What do you mean by ` flex class and empty rules `?? Just be specific about the error you are pointing here.

Comment: Back. Wow. Exactly ten minutes. You had an empty img rule, and in the .header rule  uses the `display:flex` ruling.

Answer (score 1):

Title above is align image into right, below description is align span to right assuming aligning span to right image to left answering this question. Here below i created a class named right whose css says **float:right;** and left whose css says **float:left;** ,  basically it aligns the position of an element. I am doing it for you to understand the css

```css
.right
{
float:right;
}
.left
{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" class="left" id="logo">
        <div class="headerText">
            <span class="right">WYJĄTKOWA PIOSENKA NA URODZINY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Keep it nice "you don't know basic css" isn't really necessary. Inviting her to learn CSS, explaining the elements, the style tags etc makes more sense. Like myself, you also failed to read the title (hence I deleted my answer) - which asks for the Image to be aligned.

Comment: Yes and no. All of my criticisms are correct. But if I hadn't had a downvote, I might have only flagged it.

Comment: sorry brother someone might have modified it, but thanks for your concern, i should have  considered the title rather i studied the body i will change answer as necessary

Comment: i am just apologizing for my rude behavior

Comment: OP has already been asked to specify her needs. Until then, a comment war will lead nowhere...

Comment: Please. Stay. Out. Sorry for the attitude. Really am. @agrm

Comment: Thank you very much guys for every answer and comment! You rock!