# How do i move the image to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image doesn't load up under the heading and paragraph. I am unable to move my image on to the right of the page is there a way to make the image come on to the right side of the page?.

Here  is my HTMl, CSS and JavaScript :

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("myDi").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* Center the loader */

#loader {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/* Add animation to "page content" */

.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    bottom: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#MyDi {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

  <div id="loader"></div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <h2>x</h2>
    <p>x</p>
    <img id="image1" src="./images/ohridindex.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right align an image using CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214893/right-align-an-image-using-css-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` to place the text and image side by side.

I've set `justify-content` to `space-between`, which evenly distributes the items on the first line, pushing them to either end. If you don't want this and want the items adjacent to each other, you can remove this line - see my second code snippet at the bottom.

I've used `align-items: center` on the flex container so that the text and image are vertically aligned as well.

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

  <div id="loader"></div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <div>
      <h2>x</h2>
      <p>x</p>
    </div>
    <img id="image1" src="./images/ohridindex.jpg" alt="image" />
  </div>
```

Without `justify-content: space-between` and instead horizontally centering the content:

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

  <div id="loader"></div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <div>
      <h2>x</h2>
      <p>x</p>
    </div>
    <img id="image1" src="./images/ohridindex.jpg" alt="image" />
  </div>
```

Comment: That works however now my loading screen is on top of the whole page am I able to have it in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I was able to get the thing working but the image comes first before the text and also the loading is at the top of the screen I want it in the middle

Comment: @Robce Check my updated answer. Just had to change `position: relative` to `position: absolute` on `#loader`